# How to slice a tensor in keras with variable indices?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have an image of size 100x120x3. After applying convolutions on original image, I want to get a subset/patch from the image, of size 11x11x3, during training. The patch would be centered around indices "index1" and "index2". The code I am trying is written below. The dimensions of `feats_new` is same as that of the image.

```
x = Input(shape=(100,120,3), name='inputA')
index1 = Input(shape=(1,), name='ind1', dtype = 'int32')
index2 = Input(shape=(1,), name='ind2', dtype = 'int32')

feats_new = encoder(x)
patch = feats_new[:,index1-5:index1+6, index2-5:index2+6,:]
```

I get the following errors on execution:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy
array. This error may indicate that you are trying to pass a
symbolic value to a NumPy call, which is not supported. Or, you may
be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that
does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically
converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model.
```

and

```
ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 0
From merging shape 2 with other shapes. 
For '{{nodetf.__operators__.getitem_11/strided_slice/stack_2}} =
Pack[N=4,   T=DT_INT32, axis=0 
(tf.__operators__.getitem_11/strided_slice/stack_2/values_0,
Placeholder_1, Placeholder_3,
tf.__operators__.getitem_11/strided_slice/stack_2/values_3)' with
input shapes: [], [?,1], [?,1], []
```

How can I get the patch?

Answer (score 0):

To batch stuff together, all items must have the same shape. If they don't, you get that error.
The normal way to go is to pad your inputs to the same maximum length before batching